# Add scroll bar to eclipse window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin that I really like [appwrench](http://appwrench.onpositive.com/).  The only problem is that they didn't build scroll bars into one of the pop up windows.  This means if the content cant fit on my screen, I can't see it.  I've been switching to portrait mode on my wide screen display in order to make changes but this is a terrible solution.

I was wondering if there was any way I could force eclipse to open the window with scroll bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with eclipse built-in capabilities (and also not using other eclipse plugins).

If that popup window contains widgets where you can select something (e.g. text input fields or textviews), then you might be able to force it to scroll by selecting some content and dragging your mouse into the direction that you want to scroll (with mouse button still pressed). You might have seen that before as "unwanted behaviour", when you try to select some text in a text input control, where the text is much larger than the control itself.